# How to download a file as executable via elinks in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, elinks

I'd like to download a file as executable through elinks command line in linux. How to do it? by default, saved file is not executable (rw/r/r).

Comment: What would the use case for this be?  It sure seems like you are asking for a way to get hacked.

Comment: I'm doing pen testing and chmod is not available nor scp, so I was wondering if there is a way to change a file to executable

Comment: Can you run perl/python/ruby/c/c++/etc?  There are language functions that set permissions without using `/bin/chmod`.

Comment: nope, target machine is very strict (i.e chroot). There are not much options I can use on that machine

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS this is intended behaviour—there seems to be no way to change this, except you're willing to patch the code.

Comment: For safety reasons?

Comment: I'd only be able to guess, but I think that's the reason.